# Why int type is convert to Integer?

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I faced to a problem I don't understand.
I still use `int` type but code crashed because `int` is convert to `Integer`.

Can you explain me what is the problem ? Thanks.

**Code**

*Caller*

```
int excelIndex = 2
String number = CustomKeywords.'getInfo'('test', 'test', 'test', excelIndex)
```

*Callee*

```
@Keyword
public String getInfo(String dataTest, String dataSheet, String columnName, int excelIndex) {
    String cellContent = getValueToExcel(dataTest, dataSheet, columnName, excelIndex)
    ...
    return cellContent
}

@Keyword
def getValueFromExcel(String testDataFile, String sheet, String columnName, int rowNumber) {
    ExcelData data = initialiseDataDriven(testDataFile, sheet)
    return data.getValue(columnName, rowNumber)
}
```

**Error**

```
number = CustomKeywords.getInfo("test", "test", "test", excelIndex) FAILED.

Reason:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: getValueFromExcel is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [test, test, test, 2]
Possible solutions: getValueFromExcel(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)
```

Comment: You show the call to `CustomKeywords.'getInfo'('test', 'test', 'test', excelIndex)` but the error you posted corresponds to the call to `getValueFromExcel` which you didn't post

Comment: @lealceldeiro It is post, the second keyword.

Comment: You posted the keyword `getValueFromExcel` but not how you use it, how you call it, what parameters you provided for it.

Comment: @lealceldeiro on the first keyword : `String cellContent = getValueToExcel(dataTest, dataSheet, columnName, excelIndex)`

Comment: Sorry, Am I missing something? `getValueToExcel` != `getValueFromExcel`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just stupid ...

Comment: @N.Lamblin not at all https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @tim_yates ahahah thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are calling a member method `getInfo` in a static style

Either make `getInfo` static:

```
public static String getInfo(String dataTest, String dataSheet, String columnName, int excelIndex) {
```

Or, make an instance of `CustomKeywords`, and call `getInfo` on that:

```
int excelIndex = 2
def keywords = new CustomKeywords()
String number = keywords.getInfo('test', 'test', 'test', excelIndex)
```